# How can I hold a nut underneath a deck with no clearance while screwing a bolt into it?

Tags: tools, deck, bolts, cover

I have an existing deck with composite wood planks.  My kids bought me a gazebo for my grill that I would like to bolt to the deck.  Is there a tool I can use to hold the nut and washer in place under the deck while I screw the bolt into them from above?  There is no clearance under the deck, so I have to go between the boards.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Remove a board or two or use screws or lags.

Answer (score 1):

Any few suggestions. Use toggle bolts or attach the gazebo to some deck planks. Then use lag screws to secure the deck boards thru the deck into the deck framing.

Answer (score 1):

Try some sticky glue that is quick drying.

Answer (score 0):

A lock washer (split washer) between the nut and the flat washer will usually give enough grip to allow you to ratchet it down.